# How to debug package body and triggers in Oracle using toad or some other editor

Tags: plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper, plsqldeveloper, toad, plsql-package

How to debug package body and triggers in Oracle using toad or some other editor. Mainly I am using toad and SQL developer.

When I open package then it shows debug option disable in toad.

Comment: Google debug and sql developer...I have blog posts and videos. Step one is compile for debug

Comment: Debugging in Toad has been answered in a previous question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12478195/debugging-plsql-in-toad

Comment: For PL/SQL Developer, you compile for debug (there's a right-click option), then start it from a Test window using the Debug tool on the menu bar. There is a 'Test' right-click option for PL/QL objects that will build the Test window for you.

Comment: Sorry for late reply from my side Thank you very much to all of you for all of your inputs  and guidance on this. Once again many thanks.